# Document with reference to many vs Many with refenrece to document(s)

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb

I am setting up my database structure and I am unsure on what the right solution is for my use case:

- I have millions of Item documents all with static information that
  will never change.
- I have Group Documents that hold a list of key value pairs (filters) by which the Items will be grouped.
- Items can belong to more than one Group
- The key value pairs of the Group can be changed which will change which Items fall within this Group

I have 2 solutions, but unsure which one is the right one:

1. Have the Group documents hold a list of id's referencing all the Item documents that belong to the group, which could be very huge. In this solution, should the Group's filters be changed then I would have to traverse all Items, extract their Id's and assign it to the Group. This would result in a single update, but also a very large list of Item references.

Group

```
{
  "_id": "af355",
  "_rev": "string",
  "filters": {
    "key1": "value",
    "key2": "value",
    ...
  },
  "itemIds": [
    "s5f6a",
    "afaf4",
    "12dr4",
    ...(could potentially be millions)
    ]
}
```

Item (Millions of these)

```
{
  "_id": "s5f6a",
  "_rev": "string",
  "field1": "value",
  "field2": "value"
}
```

2. Have the Items hold a list of Id's referencing the Groups they belong too, which will never be very big. Should a Group's filters change then I would have to traverse all Items, and update all those that match and no longer match which could be potentially millions of updates.

Group

```
{
  "_id": "af355",
  "_rev": "string",
  "filters": {
    "key1": "value",
    "key2": "value",
    ...
  }
}
```

Item

```
{
  "_id": "s5f6a",
  "_rev": "string",
  "field1": "value",
  "field2": "value"
  ...
  "groups": [
    "af355",
    "46sdf",
    ...(Small list)
    ]
}
```

Which of these solutions would yield better performance and least use of resources or the best balance there of? If there is a better solution, I am open to ideas.

Comment: Opinion-based questions like this are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I edited the question to make it less opinion-based and provided more detail of what exactly I require.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, you'll work with the grain of couchdb if your model is immutable-ish. Any model that relies on updating large lists or objects inside documents will be prone to update conflicts once the rate of change increases.

Documents with a changing list of millions of objects will be no fun at all: almost certainly you'll have to contend with (a) frequent update conflicts, (b) long AND wide revision trees (if you're replicating) and (c) poor performance as the documents increase in size.

Small (10s of kbs max), unchanging docs is the ideal if the data set is large or the concurrent rate of change is large (for some definition of large).

Use views to stich together the current state for docs, or do more work on the client side (multiple requests) instead.